# Discordjs_status_problem

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

[image: code]

[image: error]

How do i defined memberCount i try looking at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount

```js
  let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('772658962112839680')
  let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Online');
  client.user.setActivity('akhelp and watching 15 servers', { type: "Watching" })
    .then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to ${presence.activities[0].name}`))
    .catch(console.error);
  client.user.setStatus('dnd')
    .then(console.log)
  client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: `akhelp and watching ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers and helpping ${membercount} Users` }, status: 'dnd' })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
})
```

Comment: Post CODE in the question, not picture of code - the problem is that `myGuild` is `undefined`

Comment: My favorite stackoverflow question title in a while, to be honest. But really, I recommend changing it to something descriptive of the actual problem and then posting the actual code inthe body of the question.

Comment: @Nick i fixed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `${membercount}` to `client.users.cache.size`